# How to ask excel to hold one value and compare following cells with it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns, simulation

I have column D which changes chronologically (1,2,3,4....) And then returns to 1. However, it is based on values in column G. As long as G column shows 0, value in D will keep increasing. And as soon as G column returns anything other than 0, column D will reset to 1. However, in column F I want the value from columb E based on column D. Regardless of 1,2,3 in col. D... I want the value corresponding to the earliest 1

For example,

Throw Total First

1     8

2     10     8

3     6      8

4     7      8

1     8

1     9

2     8      9

3     3      9

4     8      9

Is it possible? (Sorry, I am a complete noob in excel)

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgpGX.jpg)

Comment: Could you explain your desired result in column F with data?

Comment: Values from a single moment of changing cells, this can not be achieved by formula. You should add `vba`-tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [If Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) of Excel.

If the value of `column D` in the corresponding line equals to `1` then use the value from the corresponding line in `column E`. If it does not equal to 1 (the "otherwise" parameter of the if function) then use the value from the line directly above.

So something like

```
=IF(D3=1, E3, F2)
```

in `Cell F3` (and then "pulling down") should work.